Vector Norm $\vert\vert v\vert\vert_V$ expressed as supremum of $\vert Lv\vert$ over all bounded operators L with $\vert\vert L\vert\vert_{op}\leq 1$
Let $V$ be a normed vector space with norm $\vert\vert\cdot\vert\vert_V$. How can I show that for all $v\in V$ we have

$$\vert\vert v\vert\vert_V = \sup\{\vert Lv\vert \:\colon\: L\in \text{Hom}(V,\mathbb{R}), \vert\vert L\vert\vert_{op}\leq1\} \:?$$

It is clear in the case where $v=0_V$ and it is also clear that for all $v\in V$ and all $L$ with $\vert\vert L\vert\vert_{op}\leq1$ we get.
$$\vert Lv\vert \leq \vert\vert L\vert\vert_{op} \cdot \vert\vert v\vert\vert_V \leq \vert\vert v\vert\vert_V$$ But how to prove the latter is the least upper bound?
Any help would be much appreciated!

This is a consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Could you show me how to deduce it from the Hahn-Banach theorem?

The Hahn-Banach theorem states that if $p:V\to \mathbb R$ is a sublinear function (i.e. $p(x+y)\leq p(x)+p(y)$ and $p(tx) = t p(x) $ for $x,y\in V$ and $t\geq 0$; in particular seminorms and norms are sublinear) and $f:M\to \mathbb R$ is a linear map defined on a linear subspace $M\subset V$ such that $f(x)\leq p(x)$ for all $x\in M$, then we can extend $f$ by a linear map $F:V\to \mathbb R$ such that $F\vert_M = f$ and $F(x)\leq p(x) $ for all $x\in V$.
To apply this here, fix $v\in V$ and take $M=\langle v\rangle$, $p(x) = \|x\|_V$ and $f:M\to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(cv) = c\|v\|_V$. This then lets us extend $f$ to $F$ such that $F(x)\leq \|x\|_V$ for all $x\in V$ (which of course implies $\|F\|_{\text{op}} \leq 1$) such that $F(v) = f(v) = \|v\|_V$.
